# Symfony2 Undefined method 'findLikeFullnameArray'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have read through various solutions for this issue but none seem to work. I really want to know what is at the heart of this issue. I am going to list exactly what I did since it is relatively simple and I can't understand what I am missing.

So I have created a simple database with a table person and I am trying to generate CRUD with bootstrap which I get working fine. My issue is when I try to get jquery plugin to work with autocomplete. Next thing I add a repository to handle my query and that's when I get the Symfony2 Undefined method 'findLikeFullnameArray' message. I am trying to use just annotations so if there is something wrong in my process please let me know.

Here are my commands:
Create Bundle

1. app/console generate:bundle --bundle-name=CompanyNameofBundle --format=annotation
2. Bundle namespace: Company/nameofBundle
3. Do you want to generate the whole directory structure: yes
4. Do you confirm generation: return
5. Confirm automatic update of your Kernel: yes
6. Confirm automatic update of the Routing: yes

Create entities with crud

1. app/console generate:bundle --bundle-name=CompanyNameofBundle --format=annotation
       Bundle namespace: Company/nameofBundle
       Do you want to generate the whole directory structure: yes
       Do you confirm generation: return
       Confirm automatic update of your Kernel: yes
       Confirm automatic update of the Routing: yes
2. app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force CompanyNameofBundle  xml
3. app/console doctrine:generate:entities  CompanyNameofBundle
4. app/console generate:doctrine:crud –entity=CompanyNameofBundle:Entityname --format=annotation --with-write –no-interaction

I then create my SearchController:

```
namespace Company\NameofBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Company\NameofBundle\Form\JqueryType;
use Company\NameofBundle\Form\SearchType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Company\NameofBundle\Entity\Person;


/**
 * Search controller.
 *
 * @Route("/search")
 */
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="search")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form   = $this->createForm(new SearchType(), null, [
            'action' => '',
            'method' => 'POST'
        ]);
        return array(
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/person_search", name="person_search")
     * @Template()
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function searchPersonAction(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->get('term');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $results = $em->getRepository('CompanyNameofBundle:Person')->findLikeFullname($q);
        return array('results' => $results);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/person_get", name="person_get")
     *
     * @param $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getPersonAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $book = $em->getRepository('CompanyNameofBundle:Person')->find($id);
        return new Response($book->getFullname());
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/jquery", name="jquery")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function jqueryAction()
    {
        $form   = $this->createForm(new JqueryType(), null, [
            'action' => '',
            'method' => 'POST'
        ]);
        return array(
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/jquery_search/{phrase}", name="jquery_search")
     *
     * @param string $phrase
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function searchJqueryAction($phrase)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $results = $em->getRepository('CompanyNameofBundle:Person')->findLikeFullnameArray($phrase);
        return new JsonResponse($results);
    }
}
```

Person Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Company\NameofBundle\Person;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Person
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\NameofBundle\Entity\Repository\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person

{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fullname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fullname;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set fullname
     *
     * @param string $fullname
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setFullname($fullname)
    {
        $this->fullname = $fullname;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get fullname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullname()
    {
        return $this->fullname;
    }
    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Lastly PersonRepository

```
<?php

namespace Company\NameofBundle\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findLikeFullnameArray($fullname)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('person_repository')
            ->where('person_repository.fullname LIKE :name')
            ->setParameter('name', '%' . $fullname . '%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

In just in case here is my app/config/routing.yml

```
company_nameofbundle:
    resource: "@CompanyNameofBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked all namespaces and all the files' paths? Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that I have also run:
app/console cache:clear
and
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Comment: You can also check you have not generate a yml or xml format before.

Comment: Sylvain can you ellaborate because since I have done this several times before I want to make sure I checked everywhere?

Comment: You have to check in the  Ressources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm/ folder that you have not file generated for your entity. I had this problem before because I made a mix of annotation and xml format.

Comment: In my Resources/config/doctrine I only have the xml files generated when doing - app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force CompanyNameofBundle  xml @SylvainMARTIN
Which produced a Person.orm.xml

Comment: Ok it was just to check in case of xml format you have put <entity name="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product"
            repository-class="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository">

Comment: You totally rock! So for clarification I manually edited my <entity> in Resources/config/doctrine/Person.orm.xml  to look like this
<entity name="Company\NameofBundle\Entity\Person" repository-class="Company\NameofBundle\Entity\Repository\PersonRepository" table="person>. Why isn't that documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

In a first time, you should have a look on the documentation to have a repository like this  :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```

In a second time, you have to check in case of `xml` format you have put

`<entity name="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product" repository-class="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository">`

You cannot have a mix of `annotation`, `xml` or `yml` format to shape an entity in Symfony 2, remove all the unnecessary files.